# Inserting script/div chatbot in GTM

Tags: javascript, dom, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having problems using faqbot.
The normal way of installing it is simple :
before the closing body tag insert this (i changed the keys in this example):

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var FAQBOT = {
PUBLIC_KEY: "0000000000000000", 
AUTO_OPEN: 500
}
</script>
<div id="faqbot-00000000"></div>
<script src="https://faqbot.co/public/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

This works like a charm.
Now I want to do this using GTM, i'm positive my tag fires (on the DOM Rdy).
I first tried to just put the code inside the custom html tag because that should be a code injector on itself.. this didnt work..

Then I used the DOM Manipulation to achieve it and indeed when i check the source of my page, the tags are right there , BUT the bot doesn't work..

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'application/javascript';
var code = 'var FAQBOT = { PUBLIC_KEY:"0000000000000000000",AUTO_OPEN: 500 }';

var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id ='faqbot-00000000';   

var s2 = document.createElement('script');
s2.src = 'https://faqbot.co/public/js/bundle.js';

try {
  s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
  document.body.appendChild(s);
} catch (e) {
  s.text = code;
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
document.body.appendChild(d);
document.body.appendChild(s2);    
}
</script>
```

Why is this not working , does it fire too late ?

Comment: Yes, the Custom HTML tag should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put the following code in a custom HTML tag:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    var FAQBOT = {
    PUBLIC_KEY: "0000000000000000", 
    AUTO_OPEN: 500
    }
</script>
<div id="faqbot-00000000"></div>
<script src="https://faqbot.co/public/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

using this custom event as a trigger:

```
gtm.dom
```

and it seems to work properly:

```
Request URL: https://faqbot.co/public/js/bundle.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't , it does indeed do a call to request the script, but the chatbot itself does not work as it should.When hardcoded in the page (tested this), it keeps firing requests now it doesnt